# Is there a safe way to edit a cache variable from the command line?

Tags: cmake

As far as I know, CMake only comes with graphical cache editors. However, I need to edit some cache variables from a shell script. One way is to directly edit `CMakeCache.txt` but this is not considered safe. Or is it? If not, what is the general practice of editing a cache variable from the command line?

Comment: `-D` seems to work as expected. I think the man page is misleading because it only describes this option for setting the initial value, not for editing afterwards. Could you convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may call `cmake`:

- with `-D` option(s) for set/modify cache variables, or
- with `-U` option(s) for remove variables from the cache.

Running `cmake` will cause the project to be reconfigured, but this should be an ultimate purpose of any cache modification.