# How to unset a variable in cmake using command line?

Tags: c++, cmake

I know that in order to set a variable, we do `-DVARIABLE=VALUE`, but what if I need to unset it?

I tried `-DVARIABLE=FALSE` but it didn't work, the compiler complains about what does `FALSE` means

Comment: `-DVARIABLE=` must work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302576/is-there-a-safe-way-to-edit-a-cache-variable-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The magic flag is `-U`.  Trimmed output:

```
$ grep DOCS CMakeCache.txt 
HOUSEGUEST_BUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
$ cmake -UHOUSEGUEST_BUILD_DOCS .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /my/build/folder
$ !grep
grep DOCS CMakeCache.txt 
HOUSEGUEST_BUILD_DOCS:BOOL=ON
```

From `cmake --help`:

```
-U <globbing_expr>           = Remove matching entries from CMake cache.
```

Comment: If it helps, remember it's similar to `gcc`'s flags for macros.