# Parameterize CMake target at build stage and not at configuration stage

Tags: cmake

Is there any facility in CMake to create a target with an explicit parameter to be provided manually by the user at build-time?

What I would like is to run CMake like normal, and then to be able to provide a parameter at the time that I invoke make, as in:

```
make mytarget MYPARAMETER=123
```

The value of MYPARAMETER will become a preprocessor definition in the invokation of gcc, as in `gcc -DMYPARAMETER=123`.

The target "mytarget" should be set up in such a way that if the value of MYPARAMETER changes, then the target will be re-built.

I was thinking of doing this with environment variables but really any scheme for build-time parameters would work for my use case. What I want to avoid is having to reconfigure my whole project each time I change the value of MYPARAMETER, since it changes on almost every build.

Comment: "Is there any facility in cmake to create a target with an explicit parameter to be provided manually by the user at build-time?" - No, there is no such facility. There are several questions on Stack Overflow about that topic, see e.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75551504/how-can-i-support-build-time-variables-for-makefiles-in-cmake).

Comment: Have you considered adding a custom target that is always out of date and computes the value of MYPARAMETER and then does whatever you need to do with that value at build time?

Comment: `I want to avoid is having to reconfigure my whole project each time I change the value of MYPARAMETER` I reconfigure cmake `cmake && cmake --build` _every time_ I build my project.

Comment: @KamilCuk Then you either have a very small project or are wasting a lot of time. I *never* re-configure unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I support build-time variables for Makefiles in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75551504/how-can-i-support-build-time-variables-for-makefiles-in-cmake). I see you also use the Makefile generator.

Comment: @Corristo That may be true. What takes a lot of time on big projects during cmake reconfiguration? I found out that proper usage of cmake cache variables just make reconfiguration almost instant.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any facility in CMake to create a target with an explicit parameter to be provided manually by the user at build-time?

No. You have to rerun CMake configuration stage.

---

You can create your own compiler. Write the following shell script /tmp/cc with executable permissions:

```
#!/bin/sh
gcc -DMYPARAMETER="$MYPARAMETER" "$@"
```

Configure your cmake with `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/tmp/cc ...` and compile by exporting the variable first into env `MYPARAMTER=123 cmake --build ...`. That way you can "inject" the value of MYPARAMETER into the compiler invocation.